# NSUserDefaults Passing Variable from one view to the other

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I'm trying to pass a variable (probably going to end up being a bool or an int, I just just want to indicate the state of a UISwitch) from one view to another. I've looked into this and it seems like the best way to do this is NSUserDefaults. However every time I try the solutions it seems to crash the app. Here's what I've done in my .m file:

1. Right-click-dragged the switch to the space in between @interface and @end and created an outlet

   `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *officer1;`
2. Right-click-dragged the switch to the space in between @implementation and @end and created an action

   `- (IBAction)officer1Flipped:(id)sender {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_officer1 forKey:@"officer1"];
   }`

But now it crashes whenever I flip that switch. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Did I forget to include anything?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not designed for passing data between views, don't do that. Instead setup a data model or another direct method of passing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the whole UISwitch object to the user defaults, save the current on state (BOOL) **officer1.isOn**

```
- (IBAction)officer1Flipped:(id)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:_officer1.isOn forKey:@"officer1"];
}
```

Then to read that value, call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"officer1"];
```